# What are the Basics of Aim Leading in World of Warships

Tags: world-of-warships

I picked up World of Warships again and am currently at Tier V in the Japanese Battleship, but I can't hit anything at these distances.

**What are the basics of calculating the Aiming Lead?**

I try to compare the travel time of the bullet (little "s" marking on the corsair) with the numbers on the scale to the left and right, but my first 2 shots mostly miss. In a Destroyer or a Frigate it is not a problem, but when my shots take 30+ seconds to reload, the game gets frustrating very fast.

I tried to use the distance instead of the travel time, but that would mostly end in late shots.

Please, no answers like "it comes with time" or "you need to feel it". I want something like, "Take the traveling time x 0.8 and add the distance to it, and shoot on that number of the scale." I know there is also the factor that the ships are moving at different speeds, but I am not able to recall every single ship with its speed capacity.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have "alternate battle interface" enabled, as this gives you a readout of the shell travel time for your aim point.

If you have the dynamic crosshair enabled, the numbers on it correspond to the shell travel time for a ship moving perpendicular to your view at a speed of 30 knots. If you have the default static crosshair *and are fully zoomed in* the numbers correspond to shell travel time for a ship moving perpendicular to your view at 20 knots.

So, if a ship is moving at that speed perpendicular to your view, then you can read off the shell travel time and aim at that number. For anything other than that, though, it really does require some experience and practice, as well as knowledge of ships' speeds (and estimation of whether they are going at full speed or less)

If you're not already firing one turret first to see where it lands and then adjusting, try to do this. Alternatively, for ships that are manoeuvring rapidly, fire your turrets in close succession at slightly different locations, to give you a higher chance that one of them will hit.

It's not always easy to tell from looking at a ship whether it is perfectly side-on, or whether it is moving slightly towwards or away from you. Where possible, try to identify the ship on the minimap to check this. If it's moving towards or away from you you will need to give slightly less lead, but also aim (very) slightly below or above where you otherwise would.

It's also worth noting that while the Kongo (the Japanese Tier V battleship) has a very long range for its tier, it isn't very accurate at max range - so even if you aim perfectly, at 20km away there's a good chance that your shots will miss. It's worth getting somewhat closer to make the most of battleship guns.

Comment: additionally, AP shells usually travel faster than HE and thus need less leading. with the 5.5 update we can see shell velocity now so that helps with that. IJN BBs are normally quite accurate, though, especially when upgraded properly. I know You don't want to hear "it comes with time", but it really does... fool around in co-op mode or mod to re-enable training rooms so you can just goof around and practice without everyone else on the team getting upset.